# How to archive a wordpress site (make it read only)

Tags: cache, customization

Is it possible to make a WordPress deployment read-only? For a website that won't be updated, I'd like to make it read-only/static, so the archive is there but nobody can post, so I don't have to deal with breaches and updates?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have shell access, or access to any Linux/Unix box, you could use `wget` to download the entire site to static html files:

`wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --domains domain.com http://domain.com`

Then either upload or move these files to your web root (after backing up and removing your WP installation).

I imagine it's also possible to do this via some sort of proxy/cache setup, but I can't comment on the relative security of such an approach with any certainty.

Comment: Be aware that everything dynamic (comments, contact forms,...) will not work any more then.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the solution I resorted to was [Simply Static](http://www.simplystatic.co/) (a free plugin) – it generates a static copy of the website (including custom content).